# Get list items and check if duplicate exists

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, 2019, validation, pnp

I need help to validate if an item with the same name already exists in a SharePoint 2019 list using SPFx on the same site.

I have a custom built form that is used for other validations. In that form, I also need to implement duplicate check.

How can I do this?